# Confused as to where to place logic code in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to C#/WPF and I would like some clarification on whether I have the proper implementation of my ViewModel.

I have created a simple window with a search text box and list box for the results.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" />
```

Then I have a ViewModel with the following code.

```
private List<string> lstStr;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        lstStr = new List<string>();
        lstStr.Add("Mike");
        lstStr.Add("Jerry");
        lstStr.Add("James");
        lstStr.Add("Mikaela");
    }

    public List<string> LstStr
    {
        get
        {                
            return lstStr;
        }

        set
        {
            if (lstStr != value)
            {
                lstStr = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LstStr");
            }
        }
    }

    private string searchText;
    public string SearchText
    {
        get
        {
            return searchText;
        }

        set
        {
            if (searchText != value)
            {
                searchText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SearchText");
                UpdateResults();
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> results = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Results
    {
        get
        {                
            return results;
        }

        set
        {
            if (results != value)
            {
                results = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Results");
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateResults()
    {
        int i = 0;
        results.Clear();
        while (i < LstStr.Count)
        {
            if (LstStr.ElementAt(i).ToString() != null)
            {
                if (searchText != null && searchText != "")
                {
                    if (LstStr.ElementAt(i).Trim().Contains(searchText))
                    {
                        results.Add(LstStr.ElementAt(i));
                        Console.WriteLine(LstStr.ElementAt(i));
                    }
                }

                else
                    results.Clear();
            }

            else
                Console.WriteLine("NULL");

            i++;
        }
    }
```

I see myself writing logic in the Get or Set section of code in the ViewModel. Let's say I will have more text boxes and lists that will want to implement. Is this the correct way of coding my logic in the properties or am I completely missing the point? Please help me understand this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ViewModels should actually be pretty dumb. You'll want to define what properties they should contain, and how those should be defined (required, within a range, certain length, etc). But, the logic that generates the values for those properties, which is essentially your business layer, should live elsewhere.

Comment: No, you should not be putting logic there. Think of it this way: what does `SearchText` *do*? It doesn't make sense, it just represents the text being searched. *Methods* do things, properties don't. ViewModels by and large aren't "do-ers", its just the layer between your actual view and where the logic is actually performed.

Comment: @Ellesedil A search filter *could* be part of the view model, but certainly not where he put it. A filter is not business logic, its UI logic.

Comment: I'm not sure why you put that filter in the _getter_ of SearchText. It would expect it in the setter (typing causes the change).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't exactly right.

First, logic normally goes in the model, not the view model. That said, you have a filter, which is basically UI logic, so its probably OK here.

Second, the filter will only change when you *set* the search text, so the logic would go in the setter, not the getter. I also wouldn't inline the whole thing, put it in its own function so you can reuse it later:

```
public String SearchText
{
    ...
    set
    {
       serachText = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged();
       UpdateResults();
    }
}

public void UpdateResults()
{
     ...
}
```

The one thing to keep in mind (and there isn't really a good way around this) is that if that function takes a long time to run, your UI will *really* slow down while the user is typing. If the execution time is long, try shortening it, then consider doing it on a separate thread.

Answer (score 3):

ViewModels should have *only* the responsibility of "converting" data into another form that the view can handle (think `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `ObservableCollection`, etc.)

The *only* time where you'd get away with the ViewModel having *any* of the logic is when the logic is encapsulated entirely in a collection.  e.g. if you can get everything you need out of `List<T>`, then the ViewModel effectively has all the logic.  If you need value beyond that, it should be outside of the ViewModel.